# how to select and get the difference of entries from the same column into an additional result column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with a list of names and every name have his own salary and a title and each knight hase his own king like:

```
ID | NAME  | SALARY | TITLE  | KingNo
01 | Jones | 900    | King   | 
02 | Smith | 800    | Knight | 01
03 | Janel | 110    | Knight | 05
04 | David | 500    | Knight | 01
05 | James | 900    | King   |
06 | Judas | 150    | Knight | 05
```

But now i need to get the difference between the salary from all knights to their kings.

I know how to get each for the salary of the kings and the salary of each knights but i cant figures out how can i get the difference into a new cloumn.

Like

```
ID | NAME  | SALARY | TITLE   | KingNo | Difference
01 | Jones | 950    | King    |        | 
02 | Smith | 800    | Knight  | 01     | -150
03 | Janel | 110    | Knight  | 05     | -840
04 | David | 500    | Knight  | 01     | -450
05 | James | 950    | King    |        | 
06 | Judas | 150    | Knight  | 05     | -800
```

Could someone please give me a tip how could i get that done?
Sorry for my bad english i'm no native speaker.

best regards

Comment: Can you show the SQL Code you have so far and we will base our answer off of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know only MS SQL not MySQL... So I have try to solve your problem using MS SQL....
Below procedure may be work for you...

```
SELECT K.ID, K.NAME, K.Salary, K.Title, K.KingNo,
( CAST(K.Salary AS INT)
                 - CAST(( SELECT TOP 1
                                    KM.salary
                          FROM      dbo.KingMaster KM
                          WHERE     KM.ID < K.ID
                                    AND KM.KingNo IS NULL
                          ORDER BY  id DESC
                        ) AS INT) )  'Diff'
FROM dbo.KingMaster AS K
ORDER BY K.ID
```

Comment: #winces# This isn't a good way to do this; you're running by rows, when SQL is designed to run as a _set_ (essentially, all rows at once).  And it's unlikely that he wants to update a table, as the information is likely to go stale.  Regardless, this is a far more complicated way to do this than a simple select statement.

Comment: @JosephineDone If still you have any query then please let me know... :)

Comment: The new query isn't going to get correct results - each knight is tagged to a specific king, but your version gets some different row from the table (which might be a knight, and isn't guaranteed to be the correct king regardless).  The op seems to want to run just a `SELECT` statement - there doesn't appear to be a column to update - and he wants kings in the result too.   And what's with the casting to `NUMERIC` anyways?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.ID, t1.NAME, t1.SALARY, t1.TITLE, t1.KingNo,
    t1.SALARY - COALESCE(t2.SALARY, 0) AS Difference
FROM
    knights t1
    LEFT JOIN knights t2 ON (t1.KingNo = t2.ID)
WHERE
    t1.TITLE != "King"
```

Comment: hi explosion pils and thank you, but i think what you write needs two tables because of t1. and your t2.? But i have only one table

Comment: @JosephineDone you can join on the same table (updated answer since I had them named differently)

Comment: thank you! i didnt know that i can join the same table twice, like i said im new to mysql, thank you, i will try it tomorrow and will inform you tomorrow.